# Woocommerce user account page load entries without whole reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with my woocommerce installation. When I click in the unser account overview on a menu item the whole page is reloading every time and that makes it so slowly. Is there a solution that on first account page visit the whole pages loads and when you click for examply on "My Orders" just the content for this is loading and not the whole page.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it with the native woocommerce user account pages.

You need to create new template page with all datas in tabs (for example) and load different part via css/js script.

Comment: what is with ajax load? Is it possible to deactivate site normal site load by clicking for example "My Orders" and write a function like this: 
$("#reload-button").click( function() {
  $('#testcontainer').load(document.URL +  ' #testcontainer');
 });

Comment: Yes, with a new account page it's possible, each links from the account menu can be modify and any js script load. You can do what you want, but it definitly depends on how many time you are ready to spend on this. Did you search about à plugin to do this?

Comment: No I don't searched because i thought that there are no plugins like this

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/ss-woocommerce-myaccount-ajax-tabs/16948806 what do you think about this?

Comment: Yes seems to do what you need

Comment: Haha thanks ;D sometimes people need a little memorial+

Comment: No problem, hope everything will go fast with this !